# Subtracting One Row from Another

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Please help me, I cant solve this problem for a whole day
I have rows like

```
Id   Serial  StockCode  StockTitle  ActionType  
1    123     D-005      Desk        Income      
2    345     C-005      Chair       Income      
3    123     D-005      Desk        Expense     
4    685     C-005      Chair       Expense     
5    345     C-005      Chair       Expense
```

The task is to calculate the stock serials balance if there are rows with ActionType-Income, insert a resulting row(using UNION or smth else).
The result row should subtract one row from another with the same Serial. So in our case the 
resulting table should look something like

```
Id   Serial  StockCode  StockTitle  ActionType  
1    123     D-005      Desk        Income      
2    345     C-005      Chair       Income      
3    123     D-005      Desk        Expense     
4    685     C-005      Chair       Expense     
5    345     C-005      Chair       Expense  
___________________________________________
*    685     C-005      Chair       Balance 

The
```

Comment: What client are you using? Or is it pure sql?

Comment: I use SQL Management Studio + WPF as client + Devexpress for Server

Comment: so you should probably remove the mysql tag then ... ?

Comment: The same logic goes for MYSQl, I dont think it depends on Client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I built a fiddle that counts up the Incomes as +1 and expenses as -1, and gives you a total count per serial number.  Built in MySQL but seems pretty generic.

```
Select sum( IF(ActionType = 'Income', 1, -1) ) as Balance, 
 Serial, StockCode, StockTitle
 from Table1
GROUP BY serial;
```

ends up with

```
COUNT   SERIAL  STOCKCODE   STOCKTITLE
 0          123 D-005           Desk
 0          345 C-005           Chair
-1          685 C-005           Chair
```

Which I *think* is correct given your example.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ce8e0/1  sqlfiddle text-to-DDL import is dreamy :)